# React Redux dispatch 2 actions based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to change store on (addList) event and check if this is the first list an array of lists to fire (selectList) event and add it to (state.selectedList.list). Now (selectList) is used whenever onClick event is working on an array of lists. 
The question is when and how should I handle the event of adding first added a list to selectedList and than use (selectList) only onClick event as I used before.

```
export default connect(
      state => ({
        lists: getEntities('lists')(state),
        selectedList: state.selectedList.list
      }),
      dispatch => ({
        addList: (name) => dispatch({type: 'ADD_LIST', payload: name}),
        selectList: (listId) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_SELECTED_LIST', payload: listId})
      })
    )(Lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both of `name` and `id` of list you adding by click, then it could be done right in the addList handler:

```
addList(name, id) { // bound with click
  const size = this.props.lists.length
  this.props.addList(name)
  if(!size) {
    this.props.selectList(id)
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to wait for list is created (to get the `id`) and then dispatch selectList action. The dirtiest solution could be just:

```
addList(name) { // bound with click
  const size = this.props.lists.length
  this.props.addList(name)
  if(!size) {
    // don't do that! it's just for proof of concept
    setTimeout(() => this.props.selectList(this.props.lists[size].id))
  }
}
```

Going further, you may use `componentWillReceiveProps` hook to catch the `lists.length` becames 1 and then trigger `selectList` normally:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const previousSize = this.props.lists.length
  const size = nextProps.lists.length
  if(previousSize === 0 && size === 1) {
    this.props.selectList(nextProps.lists[size].id))
  }
}
```

Another option would be a reducer where we don't deal with new list `id`, but only with a previous lists size (and no need for additional action trigger):

```
case ADD_LIST:
  return {...state,
    lists: [...state.lists,
      action.newList
    ],
    selectList: {...state.selectList,
      list: !state.lists.length ? action.newList : state.selectList.list
    }
  }
```

At last, instead of all above, the action creator (the favorite one for me):

```
export function addList(name) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const size = getState().lists.length
    const newList = generateNewListByName(name)
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_LIST,
      newList
    })
    if(size === 0)
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_SELECTED_LIST,
        selectedListId: newList.id
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The last pice needs to be adapted to your infrastructure, but the main idea remains the same: do some logic by some previous state condition (`size === 0`).

Comment: but if I am not using class component and don't have access to componentWillReceiveProps, but functional component?

Comment: @serj I added some more thoughts to the aswer, they could be applied in case of functional component.